# Main Method and 2 other methods using Arrays

Tags: java, arrays, random, methods

Here is the breakdown of what I am trying to accomplish essentially step by step: 
**Method 1**:This method will generate ONE random number within a specified range.
The method datatype will be an integer because it will return the random number.
The parameter list will contain two integer parameters as follows:
The first parameter will be an integer representing the span of the range.  Remember - this will be an integer variable.
The second parameter will represent the value you want to shift the random numbers by.  Remember - this will also be an integer variable.
The body of the method will generate one random number within the range of the two parameters sent to it.
Return the random number.
**Method 2:**  This method will print out an array of integers.
The method datatype will be void because it doesn't return any data.
The parameter list will contain two parameters as follows:
The first parameter will be an integer array.
The second parameter will be an integer that is the size of the array.
The body of the method will contain a FOR loop that will print out the numbers in the array.
Do the following in your **main method:**
Declare an array of size 20 that will contain 20 integers.
Generate 20 random integers with a range of 1 to 10 and place them into this array.
Use a FOR loop that will run from 1 to 20 to fill the array.
Within the FOR loop, call Method 1 to generate one random number at a time as you place it in the array.
Send the method the beginning value of the range.
Send the method the ending value of the range.
Display the contents of the array. 
-Call Method 2 to print out the array.
Send the method the array.
Send the method the size of the array.
Output of the program:
•Display the entire array.
Here is my code, I feel like I am placing my methods in the wrong areas and the wrong information in some but am even confused how I got this far. Thanks in advance:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
class Main{
public static final Random RND_GEN = new Random();
public int[] createNum(int[] randomNumbers) {
for (int i = 0; i < randomNumbers.length; i++) {
randomNumbers[i] = RND_GEN.nextInt(10) + 1;
}
return randomNumbers;
}

public void printNum(int[] randomNumbers){
for (int i = 0; i < randomNumbers.length; i++) {
System.out.println("Number " + i + " : " + randomNumbers[i]);
}

}
public void run() {
Scanner inputReader = new Scanner(System.in);
int x = 1;
do {
int[] numbers = new int[20];
numbers = createNum(numbers);
printNum(numbers);
System.out.print("Restart Program?, Enter 1 for YES, 2 for NO: ");
x = inputReader.nextInt();
} while (x == 1);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
Main go = new Main();
go.run();
}
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @Stewart The question is how to morph this code into the perimeters set in the description. Thanks

Comment: Nope, still can't see a question. Just a massively long paragraph of words. (Are you sure you've read the question yourself, and haven't just copied'n'pasted it?)

Comment: Hint: the easier it is for people to read your question, the more willing they may be to help. Nobody here owes you help. You got to put some effort in.